# Replace symbol before match using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace, match, symbols

I have strings such as:

```
text1 = ('SOME STRING,99,1234 FIRST STREET,9998887777,ABC')
text2 = ('SOME OTHER STRING,56789 SECOND STREET,6665554444,DEF')
text3 = ('ANOTHER STRING,#88,4321 THIRD STREET,3332221111,GHI')
```

Desired output:

```
SOME STRING 99,1234 FIRST STREET,9998887777,ABC
SOME OTHER STRING,56789 SECOND STREET,6665554444,DEF
ANOTHER STRING #88,4321 THIRD STREET,3332221111,GHI
```

My idea: Use regex to find occurrences of 1-5 digits, possibly preceded by a symbol, that are between two commas and not followed by a space and letters, then replace by this match without the preceding comma.
Something like:

```
text.replace(r'(,\d{0,5},)','.........')
```

Comment: Should there be a space in the second line after `OTHER STRING`?

Comment: Will ANOTHER STRING, SOME OTHER STRING, and SOME STRING ever contain commas? Are you working with a CSV generally or do these just happen to be comma separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use `regex` module instead of `re` then possibly:

```
import regex
str = "ANOTHER STRING,#88,4321 THIRD STREET,3332221111,GHI"
print(regex.sub(r'(?<!^.*,.*),(?=#?\d+,\d+)', ' ', str))
```

You might be able to use `re` if you sure there are no other substring following the pattern in the lookahead.

```
import re
str = "ANOTHER STRING,#88,4321 THIRD STREET,3332221111,GHI"
print(re.sub(r',(?=#?\d+,\d+)', ' ', str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to read alternative if SOME STRING, SOME OTHER STRING, and ANOTHER STRING **never** contain commas:

```py
text1.replace(",", " ", 1)
```

which just replaces the first comma with a space

Comment: smart solution! but sometimes the first comma should not be removed, when the additional digits are not in the string, like text2

Answer (score 0):

Simple, yet effective:

```
my_pattern = r"(,)(\W?\d{0,5},)"

p = re.compile(my_pattern)

p.sub(r" \2", text1) # 'SOME STRING 99,1234 FIRST STREET,9998887777,ABC'
p.sub(r" \2", text2) # 'SOME OTHER STRING,56789 SECOND STREET,6665554444,DEF'
p.sub(r" \2", text3) # 'ANOTHER STRING #88,4321 THIRD STREET,3332221111,GHI'
```

Secondary pattern with non-capturing group and verbose compilation:

```
my_pattern = r"""
    (?:,)           # Non-capturing group for single comma.
    (\W?\d{0,5},)   # Capture zero or one non-ascii characters, zero to five numbers, and a comma
"""

# re.X compiles multiline regex patterns
p = re.compile(my_pattern, flags = re.X)

# This time we will use \1 to implement the first captured group
p.sub(r" \1", text1)
p.sub(r" \1", text2)
p.sub(r" \1", text3)
```